# Lemonbar-XFT: Emoji Font Issue

Tags: bash, shell-script, emoji, lemonbar

```bsh
echo ☠ | lemonbar -p -b -B #000000 -f JoyPixels-15
```

The panel is showing the skull and not the face. From what I can tell, emojis with less than 5 digit codes are working. There must be a fix for this, right!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually not a font issue, but a shell syntax problem; so it's not a Emoji Font Issue - the font is not used at all.

The character `#` starts a comment, so the line

```
echo ☠ | lemonbar -p -b -B #000000 -f JoyPixels-15
```

is the same as

```
echo ☠ | lemonbar -p -b -B
```

You can escape the `#` and use `\#000000`, or quote the whole string and use `'#000000'`.
But you can not use `'\#000000'`!

Comment: I see! The font issue was not fixed btw but I appreciate the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

<s>There is a fork (Of a fork) that I found, I didn't look at what exactly was changed in this fork, but for me it solved the emoji problem.</s>

https://github.com/seitokaichou/bar

The fork I mentioned doesn't seem to support clickable areas, but luckily I found another one. It's just one commit ahead of the xft-fork, and that one commit added support for more utf-8 chars. Here is the link:

https://github.com/freundTech/bar